# WhatsApp web - recently used emoticons are not saved

Tags: google-chrome, whatsapp

I am using WhatsApp web on Chrome on my PC (Win 10, 64 bit).

For some reason, recently used emoticons/emojis are simply not saved, which I do see working fine on another PC I have (and it always worked fine for me since I've been using this web app).

I don't understand why they are not saved and what can I do in order to get them saved for the next time I want to insert one.

Of course, on my phone itself (iPhone 7 Plus, in this case), it is working just fine, as it always has.